# Dark spots showing up on furniture, etc. under coco palm

Tags: palm

We have 5 Malay coconut palms (yellow coconuts, rather than green). Under just one of them, we’re getting dark spotting on patio chairs and everything else in the vicinity. Someone said it could be insect droppings from an infestation of that tree. A systemic insecticide into the soil was suggested True? Recommendations?

Comment: A picture of the underside of the leaves would help.  Are the dark spots sticky?

Comment: check the whole tree from top to bottom, examining backs of leaves and every part of the foliage -you're looking for anything that shouldn't be there, like scale insect, mealybug or aphid infestation.